# Word 2003 crashed and I've lost my file

Tags: data-recovery, crash, microsoft-word-2003

I was working with a document located on USB. Suddenly word 2003 crashed and I've lost my file. only in the folder "recent" there is a trace left by which seems to contain less information. I've tried to open it from word history but it does not work. and also there is no back up then. any suggestions for recovery? By the way, I'm using XP 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

To recover accidentally deleted files or files that simply gone missing by getting deleted, i would recommend [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).

I have personally used it a lot of times with great success, whether from hard drives or flash drives.

From their website its description is:

> Accidentally deleted an important file? Lost something important when
>   your computer crashed? No problem! Recuva recovers files deleted from
>   your Windows computer, Recycle Bin, digital camera card, or MP3
>   player. And it's free!